# $d(x,y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

Given any map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,
define the following function 
$$d(x,y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$$
for  $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

It seems to me - please confirm - that as soon as $f$ is injective, $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Also, I think - please again confirm - that $\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded wrt to $d$ if and only if $f$ is bounded.

If I made no mistakes so far, I am asking myself if it possible to characterize all $f$'s such that $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ is a *complete* metric space.
What about compactness?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are right: $d$ is a metric if and only if $f$ is injective and $(\mathbb R,d)$ is bounded if and only if $f$ is bounded.

Assuming now that $f$ *is* injective, then $(\mathbb R,d)$ and $f(\mathbb R)$ (endowed with the usual metric from $\mathbb R$) are isometric. Therefore

- $(\mathbb R,d)$ is complete if and only if $f(\mathbb R)$ is complete;
- $(\mathbb R,d)$ is compact if and only if $f(\mathbb R)$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks very much! So we could argue further that $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is complete iff $f(R)$ is closed and compact iff $f(R)$ is closed and bounded?

Comment: That is correct indeed.

Comment: Perfect - accepted - thanks again

Comment: I'm glad I could help.